# How to save plotly graph (python) and send by email?

Tags: python, html, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe and I made a graph with the variables I need
I need the graphic to be in the email (html) I'm developing (not in a file)

```
a = fig.plot(df['example_1'], df['example_2'])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Given the graph, I need to save it and put it in the email, and also use rotation to better visualize the data.

Save the graph and use rotation=45, get it sent by email.
I can't save the image. When I get it, the image in the email (html) is in error or blank.

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
fig = plt.subplots()
a.plot.bar()
fig.savefig('test.png')

for html, put in the code:
<img src="data:image/{test};base64, {b64encode(test).decode('ascii')}">